# How can I reference static properties in defined in global.asax from within my WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I have a WCF RESTful service with a property defined in `global.asax`. How can I reference properties defined in global.asax from within my Service?

Comment: Is this property being set inside of your global.asax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you declared your app in global.asax.cs as:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
```

use :

```
Global.MyProperty
```

for a static

```
((Global)HttpContext.ApplicationInstance).MyProperty
```

for a property

to incorporate the .cs file, add it to the project and change the markup tag thus:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Global" %>
```

**edit**

to enable httpcontext add this to your config

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
```

Comment: My understanding is that HttpContext is null from within a WCF service.. ?